# Rails assets get different hash on AWS Beanstalk servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails app deployed to beanstalk, 2 nodes.
The app runs smoothly, but assets seem to misbehave.
It seems that each EC2 node in beanstalk generated different fingerprint hashes for the assets. As the assets content is the same (singular `eb deploy` made) I'm puzzled what can cause one server to generate an asset hash different than the other?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with your setup, but you should probably  precompile the assets locally before deployment.

Comment: @zwippie yup, that turned out to be the root cause. the files WERE compiled locally, but had a bug that prevented the compiled assets from being included in the git commit that was issued to beanstalk. So your answer led to the solution. thx